# simple adder isn't working

Tags: linux, assembly

I made simple arguments adder with assembly but it isn't working

it always return 0

```
    .section .data
    .section .text
    .global _start
_start:
    call adder
    movl %eax,%ebx
    movl $1,%eax
    int $0x80
adder:
    pushl %ebp
    movl %esp,%ebp
    movl $0,%eax        #eax = return
    movl $1,%ebx        #ebx = index
    movl 8(%ebp),%ecx    #number of args
loop:
    cmpl %ebx,%ecx
    jg exit
    addl 8(%ebp,%ebx,4),%eax
    incl %ebx
    jmp loop
exit:
    movl %ebp,%esp
    popl %ebp
    ret
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few problems with this code, but you're on the right track.

#### 1. Loop condition

You are using this to quit the loop when `ebx >= ecx`:

```
cmpl %ebx,%ecx
jg exit
```

The syntax is rather confusing, but this actually means "exit if ecx is greater than ebx". Changing it to `jng exit` fixes this problem.

#### 2. Arguments on stack

You are referring to arguments with `8(%ebp,%ebx,4)`, but the arguments actually start at `12(%ebp)`. You are right in that you should start with index 1, because the argument with index 0 is merely the name of the program.

#### 3. Arguments are always strings

The arguments on the stack are only pointers to strings. `movl 12(%ebp),%eax` will not put a number from the command line in `eax`. It will only put a memory address in eax, which points to a series of characters that make up the first argument.

To get the number represented by the string "123" you need to parse it with a function such as [atoi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atoi). atoi will then return 123 in `eax`.

Here's what the code looks like once these things are fixed. I put a comment next to each changed line.

```
    .section .data
    .section .text
    .global _start
_start:
    call adder
    movl %eax,%ebx
    movl $1,%eax
    int $0x80
adder:
    pushl %ebp
    movl %esp,%ebp
    movl $0,%eax        #eax = return
    movl $1,%ebx        #ebx = index
    movl 8(%ebp),%ecx    #number of args
loop:
    cmpl %ebx,%ecx
    jng exit                # quit if ecx is not greater than ebx

    pushl %eax              # save registers on stack
    pushl %ecx              # because they will be destroyed soon

    pushl 12(%ebp,%ebx,4)   # push next argument pointer on stack
    call atoi               # invoke atoi, this destroys registers eax,ecx,edx
    add $4,%esp             # restore stack pointer

    mov %eax,%edx           # atoi returns the value in eax, save that to edx
    popl %ecx               # restore ecx from stack
    popl %eax               # restore eax from stack

    addl %edx,%eax          # add parsed number to accumulator

    incl %ebx
    jmp loop
exit:
    movl %ebp,%esp
    popl %ebp
    ret
```

And the program seems to work now:

```
$ gcc -nostartfiles test.S -m32 && ./a.out 1 2 3 4 5 ; echo $?
15
```

The program returns the result in its exit value, which means it can not count higher than 255 :)
It would probably be better to let the program print the result to stdout, using `printf`.

Comment: Do I have to implement atoi myself? or any easy way there?

Comment: ah! gcc -nostartfile test.s -m32. it works! I just confused sorry